# Update and Delete row from table in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I`m learning meteorjs, and I have some problems in my test project.
This is my html file:
[reservation.html](https://github.com/sahovat/myFirstAppFormMeteor/blob/master/tmpl/reservation.html)
and this is .js file:
[reservation.js](https://github.com/sahovat/myFirstAppFormMeteor/blob/master/restaurant.js)
My first problem is with updating the row. When I click edit button, it does not get proper value from select inputs, it gets default value from input. After closing edit model, I can not add new reservation, when I  click add reservation button it shows update model, After refreshing page it opens add model. 
Second problem is with deleting row, When I click delete button, it does not delete the row. Please can you help me to solve my issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all Set all other sessions in each and every button click to the false.
suppose if click on add button set edit value session to false

```
Session.set('editItemId',false);
```

first problem solution:

when you click on edit button store that record id in one Session variable like:

```
 'click .editItem': function(){
    Session.set('editItemId', this._id);
  }
```

And check for id equlity:

```
Template.templatename.helpers({
  editing: function(){
  return Session.equals('editItemId', this._id);
} 
});
```

if both ids are equal it returns to editing mode.

And [follow the link for full reference for edit values.](http://douglashirsh.com/2015/02/06/meteor-js-part-4-editing-input-validation/)